# How to get txid after successful invoke operation | hyperledger fabric 2.x

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

In HLF 1.4 I can get transaction id after successful invoke operation. But In HLF 2.x I am not getting txid. I can see the data which I submitted to hlf in state database (couch db). Then why I am not getting txid. Here is last line in chaincode,

```
return shim.Success(nil)
```

submit transaction using node sdk.

```
result = await contract.submitTransaction(fcn, args);
console.log("Result:", result.toString())
```

The above line gives empty. Help me to get tx id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function `submitTransaction` has only [1 line of code](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/main/fabric-network/src/contract.ts#L213):

```js
return this.createTransaction(name).submit(...args);
```

So you can use this code instead of your code:

```js
const transaction = contract.createTransaction(fcn);
const result = await transaction.submit(...args);
console.log("Result:", result.toString())
console.log("TxID:", transaction.getTransactionId());
```

Comment: Where fcn is the name of the function => `const transaction = contract.createTransaction('NameOfTheFunction'); \n const result = await transaction.submit(...args);`

Answer (score 0):

To add to @harisato_vn excellent answer, I've found that the official docs [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/module-fabric-network.Transaction.html) use a capital letter at the end like `getTransactionID()`, but it actually is `getTransactionId()`. It drove me crazy for a little while.